# Unable to install TastyIgniter

Tags: php, installation, localhost

I have downloaded [TastyIgniter](https://github.com/tastyigniter/TastyIgniter) from GitHub and running it in localhost (Windows with WAMP and PHP version 7.1.9). In the last step of installation, I am getting errors that "Downloaded files from server are corrupted" and "Missing vendor files". May I know what is causing these errors and how I can run it without bugs in my localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Run `composer update` command in the root of your project.

If composer is not installed. Download it from this link [official website](https://getcomposer.org/).

Comment: Done.  But still facing same issue

Comment: Then I suggest you don't use TastyIgniter. The developer does not maintain this project _(Last commit on Jun 28, 2016)_. There are also too many open installation issues. This project is not good to use.

Comment: TastyIgniter 3rd version is updated just 5 days ago. Check the Link Here https://github.com/tastyigniter/TastyIgniter/tree/dev/3.x

Comment: Then I don't know what to do. You may create an issue there.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like they hardcoded something.

when you unzip the setup-master folder, keep it as it is and don't rename or move its content.

start your installation by calling:
yoursite/setup-master/setup.php

this worked for me.
I tried to run the installation previously by unzipping the files directly in my html folder and tried several fixes but no success.

after a successful installation you need to forward in your apache config / .htaccess file to the subfolder

In order to do so, don't forget to perform the Post-Installation steps mentioned here:
https://tastyigniter.com/docs/master/installation

---

I finished by aborting tastyigniter. After a successful installation and theme activation, the application worked fine then "suddenly" it throws an exception that the newsletter component can't be found. All suggested helps on the dev forum didn't help. Even after reinstalling the application it comes to the same error.

Apparently you won't come over a "professional" installation support by the developer ($$$)

Answer (score 0):

Thats pretty much my experience, I tried to install in different servers and environments running into several issues, especially it seems not to be made for anything other but specific development environment. Trying to secure installation with SSL already is an issue, that is very standard but poorly documented with this project. Having an example of how configuration files nginx go! Pay or have an experienced server admin do the trial and error. Integrated update mechanism, get your staging server and help to code. It is ok, just would be more honest to mention upfront, that running that app in production environment requieres some serious server administration skills and is nothing like installing and maintaining a wordpress or any other mainstream script.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30243750)